# Can't override sendmail_path with mail() PHP

Tags: php, email, path, sendmail

In the php.ini, the sendmail_path is : `-femail@site.com -t -i`
But, in a subdomain, I need to send email with the sender : `email@new.site.com`

I tried to use 
`ini_set('sendmail_path',-femail@new.site.com)`, 
but sendmail_path is system, so nothing append.

I tried to define sender in `mail()`, doesn't work (on the log of the server, the sender is still email@site.com, but in the email client, the sender is fine, but it doesn't matter).

I tried to define the **5th parameter**, but the function just stop working (do nothing, no error).

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

Think about how mail is configured in PHP - it's just a wrapper around an exec call (with some predefined arguments). Hence it's trivial to invoke sendmail via exec substituting your own aruments. [This is described](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) in the first comment on the page describing PHP mail config. You just need to composite your own headers (sendmail extracts the recipient addresses from the headers to fill in the envelope, any Bcc lines are stripped before the email is forwarded).

Another approach would be to use a SMTP capable abstraction layer such as swiftmailer or phpmailer - but you probably won't be able to use 'localhost' if it's configured as a slave relay.

Comment: Thanks, but can you be more explicit with an exemple please ?
Because all I see in comment is about editing the php.ini file, but I can't do that.